# Add custom code at start and end of all posts in a category

Tags: categories

I am trying to add some html code at the start and end of all posts but this HTML code need to change depending upon the category of the post.

The HTML code is a button to a quiz page. This quiz pages are created as per categories of wordpress.

So for example, all posts in the banking category need to link out to the quiz on banking. All posts in the marketing category need to link out to the quiz on marketing and so on.

I tried shortcoder plugin and WP quad ads to add my HTML code but stuck at how to different HTML code spending upon the category of post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the template associated with your Category template in your theme. If you don't own the theme, you can [make a Child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) of it to modify things.

For example, in my local WordPress dev environment, I have the theme TwentyTwenty active, and the template responsible for displaying is the `index.php` (typically it's the `category.php` or so). And the `index.php` is loading the `/template-parts/content.php` for displaying each of the post.

Now it's dead simple to add whatever you want to add and however. Suppose the code below is responsible for displaying the button you can see in the image:

```
<!-- </div> --> <!-- .section-inner -->

<?php if ( is_category() ) { ?>
    <div class="section-inner medium has-text-align-center">
        <button class="button" data-id=<?php the_ID(); ?>>Participate in Quiz</button>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

I passed a `data-id` attribute to each of the buttons, so that you can do whatever you want with each of the button individually.

[image: button after each post in category listing - WordPress]

Comment: This was helpful, however, I achieved the desired result using Advanced ads plugin.